# How to determine if a cell contains a button

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've created a cell named CELL .

My first task is add a button on the cell, which I have successfully added.
However, while retrieving the CELL I need to know if the cell is the reusable cell or not. If not, then create the cell and add the button, but if the cell exists and button does not, I need to add the button.

In my XIB I added the button in the cell. In some cells I need to show the button and in some I don't.

How can I determine if the cell contains a button? And if it does contain a button can I tag it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to iterate though subview which I personally think is bad idea.
The other approach is to set the tag of the cell say 100 for containing button.

Then you can check

```
if (cell.tag == 100) {
     // Cell with button
} else {
     // Cell without button
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use -

```
for( int i =0 ; i < [cell.subviews count]; i++) {
    if ([[cell.subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton Class]] ) {
        //Button is found, do whatever you want
        UIButton *button = [cell.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        int tag = button.tag;
    }
}
```